# syntax error on function to detect non-alphanumeric characters in a value?

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax, indexof

I know that there are hundreds( or likely thousands) of questions regarding `regex` functions in this forum.  I have read and consulted several, and by all presumptions, I ought to have the answer, and my function ought to work, but it isn't.

I have tried to build a function, in which one of the checks is for only allowing alpha-numeric characters.

The abridged version of the code is this:

```
function functionName() {
    var x = $("#inputId").val();

    //trying to locate any/all non alphanumeric characters & spaces
    var regex = /^[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$/g 

    if ( x.indexOf(regex) >= 0 ){
        alert("message");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "59,468
questions tagged
[[tag:regex]]", to be exact :-)

Comment: Something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Q8/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `indexOf`; you should be using `test`. That's also a little bit of a funny regex you're using. I've modified it below to match *valid* strings instead of invalid.

```
function functionName(){
    var x = $("#inputId").val();

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g;

    if ( x.test(regex) ){
        alert("Only contains alphanumeric characters. No punctuation or spaces!");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok!  Great thanks @Trevor Dixon! It works if the value is only made up of non-alphanumeric characters, but if I test it putting non-alphanumerics mixed in with the value, after numbers, then the match doesn't seem to work.  I don't suppose you might have a tip for that?

Comment: `x.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)`. Why look for *invalid* characters? In this case, it seems easier to define a regex that matches a *valid* string, then test against that.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  I do remember reading something about the $ closing off the string (or something to that effect) in another post.  I presume it was similar logic here.  Thanks again @Trevor Dixon

Answer (score 1):

You regex matches only strings that consist entirely of invalid characters. What you really want is one matching when there is at least one invalid character

```
var regex = /[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/;
if (regex.test(x)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the final '}'